# Regex - find last matching String

Tags: json

in the code below, I try to find the last match between **"disp_title":"** and **","subtitle"**

`{"entries":[{"uuid":"7873415c467149922fa928ad7e5f1245","enabled":true,"create":1677850463,"watched":0,"start":1678043684,"start_extra":0,"start_real":1678043594,"stop":1678055292,"stop_extra":0,"stop_real":1678056192,"duration":12568,"channel":"8826282e7ac4e65b19a4b9fd2f42e472","channelname":"ProSieben HD","image":"","fanart_image":"","title":{"ger":"Wer stiehlt mir die Show?"},"disp_title":"Wer stiehlt mir die Show?","subtitle":{"ger":"Wer stiehlt mir die Show?\nQuiz-Show, D 2023\nAltersfreigabe: ab 12"},"disp_subtitle":"Wer stiehlt mir die Show?\nQuiz-Show, D 2023\nAltersfreigabe: ab 12","disp_summary":"","description":{"ger":"Moderation: Joko Winterscheidt\n\nSchauspielerin Jasna Fritzi Bauer, Musiker Sido und Tokio-Hotel-Frontmann Bill Kaulitz sowie Wildcard-Kandidat Svenrik versuchen, Quizmaster Joko Winterscheidt die Show zu stehlen.\n\nKandidat: Jasna Fritzi Bauer,  Sido, Bill Kaulitz"},"disp_description":"Moderation: Joko Winterscheidt\n\nSchauspielerin Jasna Fritzi Bauer, Musiker Sido und Tokio-Hotel-Frontmann Bill Kaulitz sowie Wildcard-Kandidat Svenrik versuchen, Quizmaster Joko Winterscheidt die Show zu stehlen.\n\nKandidat: Jasna Fritzi Bauer,  Sido, Bill Kaulitz","disp_extratext":"Wer stiehlt mir die Show?\nQuiz-Show, D 2023\nAltersfreigabe: ab 12","pri":6,"retention":0,"removal":0,"playposition":0,"playcount":0,"config_name":"1c85e7e9d6e05c9591daf24d6f6cf348","creator":"192.168.178.51","filename":"/volume1/Video/Recording/Wer stiehlt mir die Show?-1.ts","errorcode":0,"errors":0,"data_errors":10,"dvb_eid":0,"noresched":true,"norerecord":false,"fileremoved":0,"autorec":"","autorec_caption":"","timerec":"","timerec_caption":"","parent":"","child":"","content_type":0,"copyright_year":0,"broadcast":0,"episode_disp":"","url":"dvrfile/7873415c467149922fa928ad7e5f1245","filesize":11900950464,"status":"Completed OK","sched_status":"completed","duplicate":0,"first_aired":0,"comment":"Auto recording: Wer stiehlt mir die Show?","category":[],"credits":{},"keyword":[],"genre":[]},{"uuid":"5be440b7c40ebc4db6e69e38cfd6a00b","enabled":true,"create":1677373443,"watched":0,"start":1677957300,"start_extra":0,"start_real":1677957210,"stop":1677969300,"stop_extra":0,"stop_real":1677970200,"duration":12960,"channel":"c0186f8bcad6248646043bdd3dbf9032","channelname":"Das Erste HD","image":"","fanart_image":"","title":{"ger":"Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell"},"disp_title":"Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell","subtitle":{"ger":"Spiel und Spaß mit Kai Pflaume"},"disp_subtitle":"Spiel und Spaß mit Kai Pflaume","disp_summary":"","description":{"ger":"In der brandneuen Ausgabe \"Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell\" mit Kai Pflaume stellen sich u.a. gleich vier \"Tatort\"-Kommissare ihren talentierten Herausforderern. Zu Gast sind: Til Schweiger, Iris Berben, Heike Makatsch, Harald Krassnitzer, Esther Sedlaczek, Lena Gercke, Hanna Zimmermann, Andreas Toba, Jakob Schubert, Dang Qiu und Jan Josef Liefers."},"disp_description":"In der brandneuen Ausgabe \"Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell\" mit Kai Pflaume stellen sich u.a. gleich vier \"Tatort\"-Kommissare ihren talentierten Herausforderern. Zu Gast sind: Til Schweiger, Iris Berben, Heike Makatsch, Harald Krassnitzer, Esther Sedlaczek, Lena Gercke, Hanna Zimmermann, Andreas Toba, Jakob Schubert, Dang Qiu und Jan Josef Liefers.","disp_extratext":"Spiel und Spaß mit Kai Pflaume","pri":6,"retention":0,"removal":0,"playposition":0,"playcount":0,"config_name":"1c85e7e9d6e05c9591daf24d6f6cf348","creator":"192.168.178.51","filename":"/volume1/Video/Recording/Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell.ts","errorcode":0,"errors":0,"data_errors":0,"dvb_eid":0,"noresched":true,"norerecord":false,"fileremoved":0,"autorec":"fd3841f0bdbac4cdaa68fc139a1c9bc6","autorec_caption":"Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell","timerec":"","timerec_caption":"","parent":"","child":"","content_type":0,"copyright_year":0,"broadcast":0,"episode_disp":"","url":"dvrfile/5be440b7c40ebc4db6e69e38cfd6a00b","filesize":18687886764,"status":"Completed OK","sched_status":"completed","duplicate":0,"first_aired":0,"comment":"Auto recording: Klein gegen Groß - Das unglaubliche Duell","category":[],"credits":{},"keyword":[],"genre":[]}],"total":10}`

For the first match, it works perfectly with the Regex `\"disp_title":"(.*?)\","subtitle"`

How can I catch only the last one ?

Many thanks for helping me out :-)
Steffen

Comment: Why not get all the matches and then just use the last one in the rest of the code?

Comment: This is JSON, why don't you use a JSON parser instead of a regexp?

Comment: Hi Barmar, it is because I have need to parse this text in a home automation software which knows only a regex parser adapter :-)

Answer (score 0):

Match `"disp_title"` only when it does not appear afterwards by using a negative lookahead:

```
"disp_title"(?!.*"disp_title"):"(.*?)","subtitle"
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/CKRaziGt0iVuZT).